# Repeating Sequences: Find every xth term's pattern to solve nth term.

Tags: sequences-and-series

the first term of a sequence is one. the second term is two. the third term is $3$. the 4th term is $5$. the $5$th term is $7$.

all terms after the second term repeat and follow the order $3,5,7$; for example, the first $11$ numbers are $1,2,3,5,7,3,5,7,3,5,7$...

What patterns do the $5$th, and $7$th terms have? E.g. they're all multiples of n.

I want to find patterns for the $5$th and $7$th terms to solve for the $100$th and $101$th term.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n$ be the terms of your sequence. Then for $n\ge 1$ we have:
$$a_n=\begin{cases}
1 &\text{ if } n=1
\\2\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ &\text{ if }  n=2
\\3 &\text{ if }n\equiv0\pmod3
\\5 &\text{ if }n\equiv1\pmod3\text{ and } n\ge3
\\7 &\text{ if }n\equiv2\pmod3\text{ and } n\ge3
\end{cases}$$

Since $100\equiv 1\pmod3$ we have $a_{100}=5$ and therefore $a_{101}=7$.

Comment: @Ben Take a look at [Wikipedia's page on modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). For positive numbers you can think of $x\pmod{n}$ as the remainder when $x$ is divided by $n$.

Comment: @Ben I'm afraid not $1$ has a remainder of $1$ when divided by $3$ and $2$ has a remainder of $2$ when divided by $3$. Hence $1\not\equiv2\pmod{3}$. Instead of saying $\pmod{3}$ you can just think of it as the remainder when divided by $3$. The advantage of looking at reminders with respect to $3$ is that the pattern which repeats has length $3$. Sure, you could imagine the sequence as just $3,5,7,3,5,7,\ldots$ and then add back in the first two terms. If this were the case you would get that whenever you have a remainder of $2$, you get $5$, and we would be looking for the $98$th term.

Comment: how would you apply the adding back terms method for the question: If the first term of a sequence is $3$, and each of the
following terms is found by multiplying the preceding
term by $2$, what is the units digit of the $32$nd term in
the sequence?

Comment: My Attempt: I get a remainder of zero when I divide $32$ by 4, so ignoring the first term of $3$, the pseudo-first-term is $6$. If i add back the first term the $32$nd term is $2$; i'm not correct, the 32nd term is actually $8$. What's my error?

Answer (score 0):

You have that: $a_{3n} = 3$, $a_{3n+1} = 5$, and $a_{3n+2} = 7$. So to find out what $a_k$ is , you can find the remainder of $k$ modulo $3$. So for example, $a_{100}$. Then $k = 100$, and $k = 100 = 3\cdot 33 + 1$. So This means: $a_{100} = 5$.

Comment: I'm just wondering if the following is valid:

Since 3, 5, 7 repeat you can think of at as a clock at this point. That being said, the nth term is

$(n-2)(\bmod 3)$

If 0 then 7, 1 then 3, 2 then 5

Comment: Take n = 9, then $a_9 = 3$, but $9 - 2 \mod3 = 1$

Comment: @JoeyAndres: you are correct unless you get down to $n \lt 3$ where the values are not on pattern.